# Why were comments about "compiler magic" removed from this question?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, deleted-comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61732690/865874) a couple of comments of mine were deleted. The first one even had a few upvotes and a reply.

It may be related to the fact that the second one was about compiler magic, in a maybe too cheerful tone. But *compiler magic* is a perfectly established expression, even brought back in a few [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732690/why-is-it-allowed-to-have-both-immutable-and-mutable-borrows-of-a-vector-of-nume#comment109197447_61732690) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732690/why-is-it-allowed-to-have-both-immutable-and-mutable-borrows-of-a-vector-of-nume#comment109204963_61734260).

Is there a particular reason why they were deleted? I don't think they deserved that fate, particularly the first one.

Comment: Comments are always subject to deletion. In this case they were flagged as 'no longer needed' and a moderator cleared them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand that, and if all were deleted, that would be ok. But right now the second comment is "@rodrigo Good guess, but I don't think so [...]", that lacks context, and then a bunch of comments that are not actually required, either.

Comment: Consider it partway through a cleanup _process_, then, and flag the remaining orphan comments.

Comment: What do you mean by *"brought back"* (in this/that context)? E,g., were some comments deleted and then later undeleted (brought back)? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen They mean that the phrase "compiler magic" was used again in other comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "no longer needed" flag on those comments was incorrect and utterly unjustifiable. I have no idea why it was indulged by a moderator.

When deleting comments, I firmly believe that one should take every effort to (A) preserve the contextual the flow of conversation, and (B) maintain useful information. If the comments are truly obsolete and/or have gone off the rails such that no productive or on-topic discussion is salvageable, then the entire conversational "thread" should be deleted.

As such, I've restored the previously deleted comments.

Just as a note, I'm certain the deletion had nothing to do with your use of the phrase "compiler magic". Someone just didn't like the comments or thought they were obsolete for some reason, so they flagged them as "no longer needed".